# Make dxChart use exact values for horizontal axis

Tags: typescript, devexpress

I am using a month number for my horizontal axis (argumentField: "dateMonth").

My input data has entries for month 6 and month 7.

However, my horizontal axis has made up it's own? 6, 6.2, 6.4, 6.6, 6.8 and 7.

Obviously, this makes no sense whatsoever.

How do I make it use the values given only?

Sample of code:

```
    series: [
                {
                    argumentField: "dateMonth",
                    valueField: "baselineCount",
                    name: "Baseline",
                    type: "bar",
                    color: '#00ffff',

                    label: {
                        visible: true,
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                        font:
                        {
                            color: '#000',
                            weight: 800
                        },
                    },
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the [argumentAxis.type](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/argumentAxis/#type) option to "discrete".